# Правильно ли составлен запрос SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, инспекция-кода

## Задача

Есть три таблицы:

- `track_id`, `user_id`, `listen_count`
- `user_id`, `gender`, `age`
- `track_id`, `artist_name`

Посчитать топ-10 самых популярных исполнителей по каждому полу для людей возраста 25-30 лет. Описать логику в виде SQL запроса.

## Решение

```
SELECT SUM(l.listen_count) AS Summa, u.gender (SELECT t.artist_name FROM Track t WHERE t.track_id = l.track_id)
FROM Listen l
LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.gender = 'м' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
GROUP BY l.track_id 
ORDER BY Summa DESK
LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(l.listen_count) AS Summa, u.gender (SELECT t.artist_name    FROM Track t WHERE t.track_id = l.track_id)
FROM Listen l
LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.gender = 'ж' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
GROUP BY l.track_id 
ORDER BY Summa DESK
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: поставьте метку соответствующего сервера (mysql, sql-server?). но вообще упоминание limit 20 в теле запроса, при том, что в условии числа 20 нет, уже говорит о неверном результате :)

Comment: не могли бы вы помочь составить верный запрос?

Comment: А что такое "популярный исполнитель"

Comment: тот, чьи треки прослушивались чаще всего.

Comment: алгоритм популярности то напишите? Можно считать популярным того кого прослушали больше всего пользователей, а можно к примеру, прослушано больше всего раз

Comment: Задание недоопределено. Следует выяснить - если один слушатель прослушал композицию дважды, надо это считать как два прослушивания или как одно...

Answer (score 2):

Надо иметь ввиду, что к примеру, женский пол может слушать чаще песни, чем мужской и сильно вырываться в топ - поэтому в данном виде запрос не верен. Вам нужно отдельно посчитать ТОП-10 для мужского пола и отдельно ТОП-10 для женского.

Для объединения двух результатов можно использовать [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Теперь задача разбивается на две идентичные подзадачи. Объединять таблицы лучше всего через [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html), в итоге выборка будет выглядеть так.

Так же давайте дадим таблицам нормальные имена `Listen l`, `User u` и `Track t`.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Listen l
    LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN Track t ON l.track_id = t.track_id
```

Остается только добавить нужные условия.

```
SELECT t.artist_name, u.gender
    FROM Listen l
    LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN Track t ON l.track_id = t.track_id
        WHERE u.gender = 'м' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
    LIMIT 10
```

Итоговый запрос

```
SELECT t.artist_name, u.gender
    FROM Listen l
    LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN Track t ON l.track_id = t.track_id
        WHERE u.gender = 'м' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
    LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT t.artist_name, u.gender
    FROM Listen l
    LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN Track t ON l.track_id = t.track_id
        WHERE u.gender = 'ж' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
    LIMIT 10
```

Какие значения у `u.gender`, а так же ошибки синтаксиса постарайтесь исправить сами, т.к. у меня нет по рукой MySQL для проверки и мне очень лень набивать схемы в онлайн сервисах.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное разъяснение! Увидела свои ошибки, с остальным справлюсь.

Comment: @Ass_ka, да, там скорее всего еще надо будет сумму посчитать и отсортировать по ней, как и было в вашем решении. Я этот момент тоже упустил.

Comment: Части union надо обернуть в подзапросы. Такой синтиксис со словом LIMIT непосредственно перед UNION в MySQL не пройдет

Comment: А так правильно (+сортировка и сумма): SELECT SUM(l.listen_count) AS Summa, u.gender (SELECT t.artist_name FROM Track t WHERE t.track_id = l.track_id)
FROM Listen l
LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.gender = 'м' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
GROUP BY l.track_id 
order by summa 
desc LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(l.listen_count) AS Summa, u.gender (SELECT t.artist_name FROM Track t WHERE t.track_id = l.track_id)
FROM Listen l
LEFT JOIN User u ON l.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.gender = 'ж' AND u.age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
GROUP BY l.track_id 
order by summa 
desc LIMIT 10